# How to make FBD in a vertical circle and a banked road?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

How is free body diagram of a block on an inclined plane different than that of a vertical circle (string connected to a block doing circular motion in vertical direction) and a banked road

Because there are two types of results in both cases:-
T(tension)/N(Normal Reaction) cos [some angle]= mg
And 
Mg cos[some angle]= N/T
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIEX3.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your work, in terms of the three FBD you have drawn.

Comment: I couldn’t really find my problem in vertical circle FBD cause there’s a special case that might become analogue to the ones above so forgive me for that but yeah,there’s the problem

Comment: Are you saying that you don't know how to draw a FBD of an object attached to a string traveling in a circle or an object on a banked turn?

Comment: Yeah the different results are so beyond me

Comment: What you do is draw a sketch of the object upon which you want to do a force balance, and, in this sketch, show (using arrows) all the forces acting on the object.  Does that sound very hard?

Comment: I get two separate results from the same FBD. Ncos(someone angle)=mg and at the same time mgcos(same angle)=mg how does that happen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is $R\cos{a} = mg$ in circular motion compared and not $R = mg\cos{a}$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/330695/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the general inclined plane (all red arrows are vectors)
[image]

This is the general banked ramp, notice that when you solve for anything, you can use: $a = v^2/r$ and solve for various unknowns

[image]
This is the block in vertical motion, notice that:

- when the block is at the top: $F_Total = F_T + mg$ (accel direction chosen is down)
- When the block is at the middle, $F_Total = mg$ ($F_T$ plays no role, is perpendicular to accel)

-when block is at the bottom, $F_Total = F_T - mg$ (accels up, x+ chosen is towards center)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great work. Now if we resolve the second diagram,we get two results in the vertical direction as I have stated in an above comment. I wanna know how