# Why do I get two results from a single free body diagram?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram

Calculating the component of the normal force (anti-)parallel to the gravitational force and setting them equal, I get
\begin{equation}
  N \cos \theta = m\, g.
\end{equation}
On the other hand, calculating the component of the gravitational force (anti-)parallel to the normal force and setting them equal, I get
\begin{equation}
  m\, g\, \cos \theta = N.
\end{equation}
Where have I gone wrong?

[image: My drawings of the calculation]

It's being assumed as a duplicate of an already answered question which I think is more about specifics. It addresses two separate diagrams with two situations whereas mine is more general and has different situation than the one in the question. It's like we look alike but fingerprints are different and fingerprints are what matter.

Comment: Is the block at rest?

Comment: Whatever you wanna assume,I’m just pointing this out though a bit of context might be needed,well then let us assume it’s going down the direction parallel to the incline and all the surfaces exert friction(frictionless will work tooo)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is $R\cos{a} = mg$ in circular motion compared and not $R = mg\cos{a}$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/330695/why-is-r-cosa-mg-in-circular-motion-compared-and-not-r-mg-cosa)

Comment: Two lessons here. One is the physics, but the other is about communications and technical writing: what you did wrong in writing this post was not specifying the situation that the diagram corresponds to. Thus some answers assume a "sliding down a frictionless ramp" scenario (because that is a common problem that involves a FBD like this), and you only got answers assuming "going around a banked turn" after you specified that you were interested in that case.  It's good to learn this lesson early, so now you're ahead of the game.

Comment: @dmckee The problem described here *is* a block sliding down a frictionless ramp. Not because it is a common problem, but because that is what is shown in the FBD. If there is friction, it is shown in the FBD. If the block has a forward velocity and is rotating a round an axis, it would be mentioned in the question.

Comment: @DilinFinn, you should always complete the triangles in your FBD's so you know where the hypotenuse is.  For blocks sliding down an incline, see the top figure in BCott's post.  In that picture, axes have been rotated such that "down the incline" is parallel to the x-axis, so the component of gravity pulling the block down the incline is also parallel to the x-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before summing forces as described in the other answers, I find it helpful to add a little more detail to the FBD. Here, it's easy to see that N = mg cos(theta) instead of mg = N cos(theta)

[image: FBD]

Here's a FBD for a banked road, with centripetal force shown.

[image]

Comment: Very explanatory and concise answer...

Comment: One more favour,a banked road fbd,please:)?

Comment: @DilinFinn, I added a banked road fbd

Comment: This pair of FBD's looks equivalent, but they are not.  For a block going down an inclined plane, N<mg.  For the car on the banked curve, if the car is going just fast enough for the x component of the normal force to provide all of the centripetal force required for circular motion, N>mg.

Comment: @DavidWhite, I agree, they're not equivalent. The small green arrow parallel to Nmg in the second diagram depicts the additional normal force for a banked road.. Should I have depicted it differently?

Comment: @BCott, in the diagram depicting centripetal force, the arrow for normal force should be extended such that the tip of that arrow is "level" with the tip of the arrow for $mg$.  That will make the normal force the hypotenuse of the triangle, producing the following: $F_N cos \theta=mg$ and $F_N sin \theta = F_C$.

Answer (score 8):

For any given case there are some obvious details that must not be contradicted. A FBD provides a more mathematical approach towards the question but how we form our equations is based on these critical details.

A correct FBD satisfies all these details (or observations).

For the given case, the observations are:

1. The wedge is stationary,
2. The block never looses contact with the wedge, and
3. The block accelerates along the wedge.

When you resolve the normal force vertically and horizontally, you come to two conclusions.

***Conclusion $(1)$***, Vertical Equilibrium.

$N\cos{\theta}=mg$

This equation indicates that the block is in vertical equilibrium, but this contradicts with observation $(3)$. The block must move vertically downwards.

[image]

***Conclusion (2)***, Horizontal acceleration.

$ma=N\sin{\theta}$

In this case, we know that the block never leaves the wedge but if the block has some net horizontal acceleration (as shown in the diagram), it will definitely leave the wedge. This contradicts observation $(2)$.

So, the equations that we come up with using this FBD must be wrong because they don't satisfy our observations. However, it does not mean that the FBD is wrong but the equations we come up with the FBD are wrong.

$$N\cos{\theta} \neq mg$$

When you resolve the weight of the block along and perpendicular the wedge, the resultant FBD satisfies all our observations. The two correct equations are,

Perpendicular to the surface: ***Equation (1)***, $mg\cos{\theta}=N$, this satisfies observation $(2)$.

Along the surface: ***Equation (2)***,$ma=mg\sin{\theta}$, this satisfies observation $(2)$ and $(3)$.

These equations in combined sense, tell us that the net force on the block is $mg\sin{\theta}$. The normal force has cancelled out $mg\cos{\theta}$.

Therefore, this is the correct FBD.

Moreover, we also know this by observation that the block will move both forward and downward. So, if you further resolve $mg\sin{\theta}$ vertically and horizontally, you will get the true vertical and horizontal acceleration of the block respectively.

However, if the wedge is accelerating too, you just have to form equations that satisfy the observations. ***The most important observation in either of the cases is the block is stationary with respect to the wedge's surface.***

I hope forming correct equations wouldn't be a problem for you anymore.

Comment: The first FBD is also correct. Setting up a FBD and solving the equations of motion is a universal method that works in any direction. Later in your answer you are correctly saying that there will be motion in horizontal and vertical direction, but your equations of motion for the first FBD are saying something different. Set up the equations correctly, and the problem can be solved also. You will need an additional equation though. You can state that the motion perpendicular to the slope is zero, like you did for FBD nr. 2.

Comment: I'm sorry,  but it is still not correct. Please see the edit in my answer.

Comment: The inertia term in vertical direction should be $ma\sin\theta$,  and in horizontal direction $ma\cos\theta$.

Comment: My equations are correct, perhaps we are talking about different things.

Comment: For vertical equilibrium you are stating that there will be no acceleration in vertical direction, so it will not move vertically, and for horizontal equilibrium you are saying the block will accelerate away from the slope with acceleration a. You are saying the block will start to fly away from the slope, that does not make any sense.

Comment: That's why these equations are wrong.

Comment: The equations are wrong, because the inertia terms are not correct. You say the vertical acceleration is zero, but it is $a\sin\theta$. And you are saying the horizontal acceleration is a when it should be $a\cos\theta$.

Comment: In the first case 'a' is the acceleration along the slope. The 'a' terms in the two cases are different.

Comment: You are still saying there is no movement in vertical direction, that can never be justified.

Comment: Thats the mistake OP has made in his post. Did you even read my answer? I'm telling why it's wrong. The block cannot be in vertical equilibrium. That's why the first approach is wrong. I don't know how you are seeing this.

Comment: Why would you assume it is in equilibrium vertically but not horizontally?

Comment: Because its in the question. I'm telling why its wrong.

Comment: 'Therefore, this is the correct FBD'. Then how do you explain that i get the same results with both FBD's? The problem is that OP and you left out the inertia term for vertical equilibrium.

Comment: OP has written $N\cos{\theta}=mg$.I have told why it cannot be written like this using the first set of equations. In the second set of equations, I have resolved weight along and perpendicular to the surface. I know that I have done everything correctly. Nothing is wrong with my post, you are misinterpreting something.

Comment: It cannot be written like that because the correct formula for this FBD would be $N\cos\theta -mg = ma\sin\theta$. You are making the same mistake, and when you don't get the result you expect, you say the FBD must be wrong.

Comment: The OP has done this mistake in his question and I'm am telling that this approach is wrong because there wont be a vertical eqm. This talk is over.

Comment: Nope, you are saying that OP derived the formulas for the FBD correctly, but that the FBD is wrong, when it is in fact the other way around.

Comment: Lots of vertical equilibrium talk going on. Though I wanna add, the block being in acceleration and not being in accelration is the same thing for the vector resolution of forces,it’s magnitude that makes all the difference, so yeah you can be pointing out my mistake on ambiguity, but you’re arguement for that is a wrong-to anyone who thinks the block being in equilibrium or not is gonna make a difference

Comment: And I just don’t get how you can say trigonometry isbeing wrongcause the block is/is not in equilibrium

Comment: and it’s like solving mechanics’ problems. If friction co-efficient is not given,the surfaces are smooth. You just assume that. The same way I don’t know why you would even consider that the block’s gonna fly horizontally and blame this detail for not being specified by me. I mean if I wanted to ask that,I would’ve mentioned that the block’s gonna fly and I get two fbds

Answer (score 7):

Some context is needed.  The answer depends on the acceleration.

- Frictionless ramp: in this case, the block accelerates down the ramp.  There is no acceleration in a direction normal to the ramp, so there is no net force in that direction, so $N=mg \mathrm{cos}\theta$.
- Banked turn: in this case, the acceleration is horizontal, so there is no net vertical force. Thus $N\mathrm{cos}\theta=mg$.

Comment: That was exactly what was bugging me.....    yeah I do wanna know how do I come to Different results for the same trigonometry....     Sorry for being a rough question asked but I thought providing specifics is just gonna make the question look as insincere

Comment: One has to draw FBD based on the motion that is observed. Not the other way around

Answer (score 3):

The physical principle behind problems like this is Newtons first law:
$F=M*a$
Where F is the sum of all forces in a direction.

In most school problems, there is no motion( and thus acceleration) in the considered direction, and the equation reduces to $F=0$. Unfortunately many people jump to the conclusion that $F=0$ without motivating it. Many times they are lucky and there is indeed no motion in that direction, and they get the right answer. But sometimes the assumption that there is no acceleration is wrong. In that case they get the wrong answer, and may not be able to figure out why. This is a perfect example of a situation like that. Without friction, which is the case according to the FBD drawn, the block will accelerate down the slope. A component of this acceleration is in the vertical direction, thus the assumption that the sum of forces in the vertical direction is zero is incorrect. This results in a wrong answer.

It has been suggested in other answers that the FBD is incorrect and should be solved in certain directions. This is not true. The problem can be solved by decomposing the forces in any two directions, as long as they are not on the same line. The proof below shows that the problem can be solved by decomposing the forces along and perpendicular to the slope, but also in horizontal and vertical direction.

Let's start with the easy solution, and derive the equations of motion in the direction of the slope and perpendicular to it. I'll define the t direction as going down the slope, and the n direction perpendicular to it downward. The equations are:

> $$\begin{align}
> mg\sin\theta &= ma_{t} \tag{1a} \\
> mg\cos\theta - N &= ma_{n} \tag{2a}
> \end{align}$$

Now we should note that N is not a random force, but it is the reaction force that keeps the block on the slope. Therefore the acceleration perpendicular to the slope is zero, and we will call the acceleration along the slope a. The equations now reduce to:

> $$\begin{align}
> mg\sin\theta &= ma \tag{3a} \\
> mg\cos\theta - N & = 0 \tag{4a}
> \end{align}$$

Or:

> $$\begin{align}
> ma &= mg\sin\theta \tag{5a} \\
> N &= mg\cos\theta \tag{6a}
> \end{align}$$

Now the difficult part, solving the system in horizontal and vertical direction. We will define the x direction as to the left, and the y direction downward. We then get the following equations:

> $$\begin{align}
> mg - N\cos\theta &= ma_{y} \tag{1b} \\
> N\sin\theta &= ma_{x} \tag{2b}
> \end{align}$$

Again we know that the block can only move along the slope, because N is a reaction force, and again we call the acceleration along the slope (downward) a. So we get the following equations:

> $$\begin{align}
> mg - N\cos\theta &= ma\sin\theta \tag{3b} \\
> N\sin\theta &= ma\cos\theta \tag{4b}
> \end{align}$$

Equation 4b can now be rewritten as:

> $$\begin{align}
> N &= \frac{ma\cos\theta}{sin\theta} \tag{5b}
> \end{align}$$

Now equation 5b can be inserted in 3b:

> $$\begin{align}
> mg - ma \frac{cos\theta}{sin\theta} cos\theta &= ma\sin\theta \tag{6b} 
> \end{align}$$

This can be rearranged to:

> $$\begin{align}
> mg &= ma \big( \frac{cos\theta}{sin\theta} cos\theta + sin\theta \big) \tag{7b} 
> \end{align}$$

Now we multiply the second term in the brackets with $\frac{sin\theta}{sin\theta}$ and get:

> $$\begin{align}
> mg &= ma \big( \frac{1}{sin\theta} \big) \tag{8b} 
> \end{align}$$

Or:

> $$\begin{align}
> ma &= mg\sin\theta \tag{9b} 
> \end{align}$$

This is the same as equation 5a. Inserting this in equation 5b gives:

> $$\begin{align}
> N &= mg\sin\theta \frac{cos\theta}{sin\theta} \tag{10b}
> \end{align}$$

This simplifies to:

> $$\begin{align}
> N &= mg\cos\theta \tag{11b}
> \end{align}$$

Which is again the same as 6a.

The important lesson to be learned here is to *always* write down the accelerations explicitly, and only to set them to zero after you prove they will be zero.

Comment: That’s not the point...

Comment: Your question was why your results are wrong, so I think it is the point.

Comment: Yeah I do get some of it how that makes a difference... Sorry for sounding harsh but a newbie makes the most noise you know...

Comment: Don't worry about it, i probably deserve it, done it prenty of times myself ;). Try to solve your equations paralell and perpendicular to the slope, then sum of forces is zero perpendicular, and you can get the acceleration or needed friction in the other direction. Also keep in mind that N should be smaller than mg.

Answer (score 2):

you should not resolve the normal into components 
This is because Ncosθ≠mg. There is non-zero acceleration in the downward direction.if the block is in equilibrium there is some other force pushing the block along the inclined plane. 
the force acting along the inclined plane which is pushing the body up can be resolved into components

1.the normal force is due to contact between the body and the plane

2.the mg(downward force) is due to gravity

the force which is not normal to the surface is resolved

Comment: Let’s take a banked road at a fixed angle then,there it’s a premise to write cosine times N is equal to mg...

Answer (score 2):

You have made a mistake in applying newton's 2nd law here. It says that $\sum \vec{F}=m\vec{a}$.

Since the body accelerates along the slope of the ramp (say, with acceleration $a$) there will be a component of acceleration $a\sin{\theta}$ which is along the vertical. So newton's 2nd law, when applied in the vertical direction becomes:
$$mg-N\cos{\theta} = ma\sin{\theta}$$

Suppose instead, we apply newton's 2nd law along the direction of the normal reaction, then the component of acceleration along the normal is $a\cos{90^{\circ}} = 0$. So newton's 2nd law becomes:
$$N - mg\cos{\theta}=ma\cos{90^{\circ}}=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow N=mg\cos{\theta}$$

---

Now, you can use both the FBD's to solve the problem, theres nothing wrong with that. Each free body diagram gives you 2 equations (along the 2 perpendicular directions), which you need to solve the 2 variables in the problem, $N$ and $a$. 
Normally, people use the first free body diagram, because then you don't have to solve the equations instead you directly can solve for the variables (as you have done)

Answer (score 0):

You made a very simple trigonometric mistake.

When you equated $N=mg \cdot cos(\theta)$ **its wrong.** Look up $cos(\theta)$ definition and you will understand.

> cosine:
>
> *noun, Mathematics*
>
> the trigonometric function that is equal to the ratio of the side adjacent to an acute angle (in a right-angled triangle) to the hypotenuse.

Based on this, the relation has to be, in the right top diagram, as **$N=\frac{mg}{cos(\theta)}$**

And indeed, you arrive at the same relation in your second diagram.

> **REMEMBER** : Number never lie; if they appear to, then it must be our mistake :P

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking.

Comment: @Mitchell. I identified my mistake. I'll be correcting it. But I stand by base opinion i.e. the issue is trigonometric in nature. OP has resolved the components wrongly. I had faced the same issue in my school days. That's why I could say this confidently!

Comment: Well,if you have two given lines,you can always cos theta the other with the first. That’s what I tell myself,and that works too.

Comment: So,I get my mistake then(make a triangle and all) then can u show the fbd I have to make in the case of a banked road?

Comment: @DilinFinn-I understand your doubt. My answer is wrong. I checked it. Now, for banked road FBD, Ncos(θ)=mg. But not for the case when a block slides along the wedge. The motion is different in both the cases, hence different free body diagram. The lateral component, that is Nsin(θ) will offer the centripetal force.

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting the forces correctly. But why are you setting them equal?

You do that because you assume Newton's 1st law. The problem is just that Newton's 1st law doesn't apply in both cases. It only applies in the direction perpendicular to the surface, since nothing accelerates in that direction. So, your second equation is correct.

In any other direction, there is an acceleration component included, so you must use Newton's 2nd law and include a mass-times-acceleration-component term. The first equation is wrong and should have been:

$$N\cos(\theta)=mg-ma\sin(\theta)$$