# $N=mg\cos\theta$ or $N=\frac{mg}{\cos\theta-\mu_s\sin\theta}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

As per what I've learnt and come up with, $N=\frac{mg}{\cos\theta-\mu_s\sin\theta}$ which is by resolving the components of these three forces in horizontal and vertical direction:

1. Gravitational force ($mg$)
2. Normal force
3. Frictional force in the
   the downward direction along
   the banked road.

Now,while seeing the free body diagram, I see that $N=mg\cos\theta$ can also be correct.

So, which one of these is correct? And if both are correct, why can't they be equated simultaneously?

[image]

Comment: I guess , you are deriving it  when, car moves around circular path on a banked road, right? . it seems like a high school level derivation of grade 11 , as I could remember?

Comment: Your expression (the fraction) for $N$ is incorrect. Friction points up the ramp.

Comment: @Qilinxue friction can point down the ramp if the car's tendency is to topple in the outward direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $R\cos{a} = mg$ in circular motion compared and not $R = mg\cos{a}$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/330695/)

Comment: @maverick yes, it should be there, possibly the OP is getting confused with inclined planes and banking, Aaron has pointed out

Comment: Chatrapal, there is an important point to make here.  The form of the function that describes the normal force is very dependent on the free body diagram and how the forces are applied in that diagram.  This means that there is no one equation for normal force, and you shouldn't try to memorize one equation for normal force.  Instead, you should focus on properly setting up a free body diagram, and on properly deriving the appropriate equation from that diagram.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot determine $N$ just from the free body diagram. You also need to know the *acceleration* of your body.

For the usual "block on an incline" problem, we know that $a_\perp=0$, so we can then conclude that $N-mg\cos\theta=0\to N=mg\cos\theta$.

For objects on a banked curve at a constant height on the banked curve, the acceleration is completely horizontal, so $a_\perp\neq0$ and we cannot say that $N=mg\cos\theta$. But you *can* say that the $a_y=0$ which leads you to $N\cos\theta-(mg+f\sin\theta)=0$

Introductory physics students get so used to $N=mg\cos\theta$ that they forget why we can say this in the first place. It is only valid for when there is no acceleration component perpendicular to the incline. This is a great physics lesson: don't just assume equations are always valid. You need to make sure you understand where the equations you want to use come from, and what has to be true of the system in order for the equation to be valid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106719/discussion-between-samuraimelon-and-aaron-stevens).

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem with your approach is that you are not able to see *all* the forces acting on the car. There is a difference between banking and rolling on an inclined plane.

1) rolling on an inclined plane looks like this

[image]

Viewing from the top,

[image]

On the other hand, movement on a Banked road looks like *this*

[image]

(Kindly assume that the thing on the top is a vehicle)

The vehicle in the above diagram is moving in the outward direction, which will be more clear in the Birds-eye view of the vehicle

Birds-eye view of the vehicle

[image]

Note that I have drawn an arrow representing the centripetal force towards the centre of the circle. This is because I am observing from the top. In the next picture denoting the forces, you will notice that the force acts in the outward direction (a pseudo-force called the centrifugal force).

The *actual* centripetal force is provided by friction and the Normal force. This is necessary for turning. In horizontal circular motion friction alone provides the force. The main reason for banking is to reduce the dependency on friction by seeking help from the Normal force.

[image]

Now, if you try to equate the forces perpendicular to the plane, it is wrong because the net acceleration perpendicular to the plane is not zero if you do not consider the centrifugal force. But if you do,  then the net acceleration is also zero, but you have to consider the centrifugal force.

Then, if you solve it properly, you will get

$v^2=\frac{Rg(sinθ+μcosθ)}{cosθ-μsinθ}$

Substituting it, you will get the expression that you seek. But the point is, there is a fundamental difference in banking and inclined plane that cannot be represented easily in a two-dimensional plane.

One is rectilinear motion, and the other is a horizontal circular motion.

In the former, there is a decrease in potential energy as time passes (proportional to $t^2$), in the latter, there is no change in height.

An object in an inclined plane can move without friction (it just cannot roll), but the object in a banked road needs friction and will slip in its absence. These fundamental differences should be understood properly if you wish to analyze banked road motion.

I hope you can understand the difference.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106748/discussion-on-answer-by-krishna-nmg-cos-theta-or-n-fracmg-cos-theta-mu).