# $N = mg\cosθ$ OR $N\cosθ = mg$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

[image: Free body diagram]

As shown in the picture, the free body diagram shown 2 results, N = mgcosθ and Ncosθ = mg.
I'm wondering about how and when to use each solution, and which one to use in this scenerio (Translation : What are the normal force occurred on spot A, and spot B.)

[image: The question (Translation : What are the normal force occurred on spot A, and spot B.)]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Note that the two scenarios you are showing here are fundamentally different. In the first case, the block must be moving, sliding down the incline or the like. In the second scenario, the sphere is not moving.

Comment: Closely related:  [Why is $R\cos{a} = mg$ in circular motion compared and not $R = mg\cos{a}$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/330695/why-is-r-cosa-mg-in-circular-motion-compared-and-not-r-mg-cosa)

Answer (score 1):

Note that the equations you write down (here, relating two forces) are gotten by using Newton's Second Law. So, in each, there is an implicit term involving (possibly zero) acceleration.

To know "which to use", depends on understanding the free-body diagram and the acceleration-vector in the problem. The only real freedom you have is choosing the coordinate axes to break vectors into components.

While any choice is physically correct, some choices may lead to simpler math problems.

(I see now that there are two physics problems being posed.)

Answer (score 0):

Those are two different things. $mg \cos(\theta)$ is the normal component of the weight. $N\cos(\theta)$ is the vertical component of the normal force.

In this case we know that the block is moving along the ramp. So we don’t care about horizontal and vertical components. We only care about normal and parallel components.

Answer (score 0):

In the block-on-incline scenario the block must be sliding down the incline (otherwise a friction force is missing). So, it has acceleration.

Now, why are you setting parallel forces equal to each other? There is no general law stating that parallel forces are equal.

Maybe you were thinking of **Newton's 1st law**, $\sum F=0$? This law only applies in certain special-cases, namely when there is no acceleration. In this scenario the law can thus only be applied along the *perpendicular direction* to the sliding motion (so perpendicular to the incline). So $N=mg\cos(\alpha)$ is correct.

Along all other lines, Newton's 1st law doesn't apply, and you thus aren't allowed to set forces equal to each other. Instead, **Newton's 2nd law**, $\sum F=ma$, applies, which you can use. That law holds true generally. And it involves the acceleration.

---

The second scenario of a ball-wedged-between-wall-and-incline is different. Here nothing is accelerating. So Newton's 1st law can be used without problem. Just remember to add up *all* forces along a particular line, meaning all forces from both contact points.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you can use both FBD

**case I**

the equation of motion

$$m\,\ddot s-m\,g\,\sin(\theta)=0\tag 1$$

**case II**

transfer the forces components to $~SN~$ system you obtain

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
  F_x \\
  F_y \\
  F_z \\
\end{bmatrix}_{SN}= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \theta \right) &\sin \left( 
\theta \right) &0\\ -\sin \left( \theta \right) &
\cos \left( \theta \right) &0\\  0&0&1\end {array}
 \right]\,
 \left[ \begin {array}{c} -N\sin \left( \theta \right) 
\\  -m\,g+N\cos \left( \alpha \right) 
\\  0\end {array} \right] = \left[ \begin {array}{c} -\sin \left( \theta \right) m\,g
\\  N-\cos \left( \theta \right) mg
\\  0\end {array} \right]
$$

thus the equation of motion is also equation (1), additional you obtain the normal force $~N~$ with $~\ddot y_{SN}=0=F_y\quad\Rightarrow N=m\,g\,\cos(\theta)$